# How to execute groovy script to all available Jenkin jobs?

Tags: groovy, jenkins-groovy

We want to run below script in all of our Test Automation jobs :

```
import hudson.model.*

def build = manager.build
if(build.getTestResultAction().getSkipCount() > 0 || build.getTestResultAction().getFailCount()> 0) {
manager.buildUnstable()
}
```

Is there any way to perform this activity? We have jenkins post groovy plugin with us.